# Add a char before file extension in Java

Tags: java, file

I have a file named "Hello.py" and found at the following directory:

```
C:/Hello.py
```

My aim is to make a copy of the contents of the file to another file. Am looking for a regex that takes the original file path which is a string and append "1" before the .py extension. It should look like this:

```
C:/Hello1.py
```

My Codes:

```
 public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]){
     String filepath = "C:/Hello.py";
     String newpath = "C:/Hello1.py"; // I need a way to add that regex to it.
     File originalcopy =new File(newpath);
```

Comment: Catch the last index of (hint) of the `.` symbol in your string, substring this from your entire string, concatenate a number and add `.py` to it. It's no regex though, not sure how important this is to you.

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you need regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> // I need a way to add that regex to it.

```
newfn=oldfn.replaceAll("(\\.[^.]*)$","1$1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `<extension>` with `1<extension>`:

`String newName = oldName.replaceAll("(\\.\\S+?$)","1$1");`